# If $p = n(n^2-1)(n^2-4)\cdots(n^2-100)$ then how is $p$ divisible by $(21!)$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, divisibility, factorial

I found this question in a book, I have no idea how to approach this problem. I can expand and write $$p = (n-10)(n-9)....n(n+1)....(n+10)$$ but I don't know what to do next.

Moreover the book says that since $p$ is divisible by $21!$, it will hence be divisible by $2!3!4!5!6!$, by $(5!)^4$, by $(10!)^2$ and by $10!11!$. Why is this so? If it is divisible by $21!$ I understand why, for instance it is divisible by $10!$ or $11!$ alone, but I cannot understand why it is divisible by $10!11!$.

How do I begin this problem? How can I figure out how $p$ is divisible by $21!$ when I have no idea what $n$ is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Part of the question has already been answered by @J.G.
>   $$\frac{(n+10)!}{(n-11)!}=21!\binom{n+10}{21}$$

Note that

\begin{align}
\frac{21!}{11!}&=21\cdot20\cdot19\cdot18\cdot17\cdot16\cdot15\cdot14\cdot13\cdot12\\
&=3\cdot7\cdot\color{red}2\cdot \color{red}{10} \cdot19 \cdot \color{red}9 \cdot2\cdot17\cdot\color{red}8\cdot\underbrace{2\cdot3}_{\color{red}6}\cdot\color{red}5\cdot\color{red}7\cdot2\cdot13\cdot\color{red}4\cdot\color{red}3\cdot\color{red}1\\
&=10!\times\ldots
\end{align}

Answer (score 6):

Your product is $\frac{(n+10)!}{(n-11)!}=21!\binom{n+10}{21}$.

Comment: I'm so sorry to ask such a silly question, but how exactly do you take out the 21! from (n+10)!/(n-11)!? What is the method used?

Comment: @Hema I assume by $n+1$ you meant $n+10$. If you know the formula for binomial coefficients...

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant n+10, which formula do we use to take out the 21!? I am a bit new to these topics actually..

Comment: @Hema https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Factorial_formula

Comment: Thank you! I got it now. I actually got confused with the notation, but now I got it.